# meteor target builds with conditional file inclusion

Tags: meteor

I'd like to build a mobile app and a richer desktop app together.  I could manage this with

1. git branches
2. git projects
3. soft links in the file system
4. Running a preprocessor that selectively hides inputs from the build process
5. Finding a hook into meteor's build process that can be taught to selectively exclude inputs

and would like to hear if there are success stories.

But my primary preference would be to get 'conditional compiles' by either 4 or 5

Has anyone gone far down any of these roads?  Is there another way I should consider?

Thanks!

This is also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/iLMNUgnNTSA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've argued that the package system for Meteor should include better logic for conditionally including files:

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1292

But in general, you can definitely attach all sorts of things to meteor's build system. The default coffeescript and stylus preprocessors are just plugins for the meteor toolchain.

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/coffeescript
>   https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/stylus

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  It seems the best way to me.